# What is a contextual algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I've been around some research articles which talks about Contextual Algorithms. I want to know what is a contextual algorithm in computing in general.

Comment: Can you provide a link to such an article?

Comment: @ttnick If you Google for `"contextual algorithm"`, you get about 9000 hits. The first few for me include paper titles such as "A contextual algorithm for AVHRR fire detection" and "Development of an Efficient Contextual Algorithm for Discrimination of Tall Vegetation and Urban for PALSAR Data". (Actually, a lot of them seem to be about fire detection.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I did a brief search and obtained results about e.g. "contextual multi-arm bandit problems". I am not familiar with any of these but the different topics seem rather unrelated to each other. That is why I asked for a bit more context (pun not intended here).

Comment: @ttnick \*groan\* nonetheless.